# xsltlistview overiding the column headings using Xsl Link

Tags: column, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a listview webpart that used specific columns.

Changing the names of the columns is not an option.

Our users are insisting that the heading for these columns be updated, so I am thinking of using XSLT to achieve this. I believe it is possible using the XSL Link field of the webpart.

So, as an example, I have 
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3

and it must display as

Column A | Column B | Column CC

Does anyone have an example on how to do this?

Comment: Mahendran, usually when this situation occurs I make Calculated Fields for the columns with simple formula =[Field] and give column names as I want! and use calculated columns in XSLT... I know its not a healthy solution, but that's the only work around I have found... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having read up on the interwebs, I came across this (awesome) post:

[Overriding the presentation of an xslt listview webpart](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/04/overriding-the-presentation-of-an-xslt-list-view-web-part.html)

which basically covers how to do what I was trying to achieve.

The steps I took to get this right are as follows:

1. Open up the page in SharePoint Designer and grab the xslt of the listview
2. Save xslt into a .xsl file
3. Update the file as you wish
4. Upload the file to the layouts folder (this is important, read [here](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/05/xlv-bug-xsl-link-property-and-the-ecb-menu.html) for a full breakdown of why it Must be in this folder)
5. Edit the xsl link field of the xslt listview, to point to your custom xsl file

Done :)